# Whats going on with this JavaScript snippet?

Tags: javascript

From http://dmitry.baranovskiy.com/post/91403200

```
if (!("a" in window)) {
    var a = 1;
}
alert(a);
```

Here are the results I got:

- Chrome console - [object Object]
- Firebug - undefined
- Safari console - undefined
- Jsfiddle - 1

What's going on??! I expected undefined, since the "if" should return a false (since "a" in window should be false, and !false should be true, therefore the variable a never gets a value). What am I missing?

EDIT: Ok, I realized var statements are executed first, and "a" in window just returns whether such a variable exists or not. But then why are Firebug and jsfiddle giving different answers?

Comment: Here, the `if` is not important since the scope for var a is only inside the if block. All results should be `undefined`. I've just test in ie, Chrome, ff, safari and all alerts undefined.

Comment: What jsfiddle.net options are you using? The default is "onLoad" (look in the sidebar) and that wraps your JavaScript in a function, that function will change the scope of `a`. Also, it isn't strictly true to say that `var`s are executed first, the `var a` will be hoisted to the top of the scope but the `a = 1` part is left where it is.

Comment: Still don't understand why [object Object] on the webkit browsers...

Comment: Chrome console outputs undefined for me. Try running it on a clean tab.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté you're right! I was running it on the tab which had that website (http://dmitry.baranovskiy.com/) loaded. Clean tab gives undefined.

Comment: Also, the answer to the question: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/01/26/answering-baranovskiys-javascript-quiz/

Answer (score 2):

This code gets seen by the javascript interpreter as this:

```
var a;
if (!("a" in window)) {
    a = 1;
}
alert(a);
```

You have four permutations for this code based on whether `a` already exists in the global scope and whether the code is run in the global scope or in a local scope.

If the code is run in a local function scope, then it essentially looks like this:

```
function whatever() {
    var a;
    if (!("a" in window)) {
        a = 1;
    }
    alert(a);
}
```

So, here are the permutations:

```
global a exists already      scope code runs in       value of alert(a)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
yes, has value of 2          global                   2
yes exists, value undefined  global                   undefined
no                           global                   1
yes, has value of 2          local                    undefined
yes exists, value undefined  local                    undefined
no                           local                    1
```

So, the variation in answers you are getting is because the scope this code is running in is different in each case.

In a jsFiddle, you have to be careful with the settings in the upper left corner.  If set to `onload`, then the jsFiddle runs in a local function scope (an onload handler function).

What's going on here is that if this code is running the global scope, then `("a" in window)` will always be true because the `var a` part of the code is hoisted above the executing code thus `var a` in global scope has always been executed so there is always `("a" in window)`.  Thus `a = 1` is never executed when run in the global scope and the `alert(a)` simply outputs whatever the value of global `a` is.  If it previously had a defined value that's what you will see.  If it didn't previously have a defined value, then it will just alert `undefined` because (thought it exists), it hasn't been assigned a value.

If this code is run in the local scope, then the `alert(a)` will always see the locally defined `a` in the `alert(a)`.  So, you will see `1` as the value if there is no global `a` because then `a = 1` will execute on the local `a`.  Or, if there is a global `a`, then the `a = 1` will never execute, thus the locally defined `a` will always be `undefined` and that's what the alert will show.